# Voice analyzer that gives you a visual response of the pitch or frequency

Tags: audio, music, voice

Do you know any good software that analyses voice and woudld return a visual representation of your pitch? I need this software to help me in teaching students to sing, The software can at least give me a visual representation so I can easily show it to them.

Please suggest a software that will help me analyze the pitch of a voice, it should be easy to use and understand good for students that wants to learn how to sing.

I am running on Windows 7, I have a Core 2 Duo CPU (2.4GHz x2), and 2GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using any wave editing software that support a spectral view. You can see the fundamental frequency of a voice recording as a wavy line (See: http://www.google.com/search?q=spectral+view&tbm=isch for sample pictures..) The lowest line is *usually* the fundamental frequency. For your purpose, linear (as opposed to logarithmic view) is more useful as it spreads the harmonics farther away in terms of pixels.

Answer (score -1):

I know Garage Band can tell you which note, however this doesn't tell you the pitch, nor is it for Windows 7.

You could try getting a piano application and seeing which note corresponds with what they're singing. While your students are at it they might learn basic piano notes too.